# Display exception information and Debug.Print() messages in Immediate Window

Tags: visual-studio, immediate-window, first-chance-exception, debug-print

A friend of mine claims that calls to Debug.Print() as well as first-chance exception notifications appear in the Immediate Window for him. I found this surprising; for me they only appear in the Output Window.

MSDN claims ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28VS.80%29.aspx)) that you can implicitly enable them in the Immediate Window by explicitly disabling them in the Output Window. But that doesn't work for me; the messages are not shown in either window if I disable this. The Immediate Window remains empty.

How do I get the Immediate Window to display this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in VS2008 and in VS2015 (did not check 2010 or 2013, but they are likely the same)

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Redirect all Out Window text to the Immediate Window

Answer (score 10):

There's a setting that will redirect all output to the immediate window. Tools > Options > Debugging > Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window.

Comment: Give me a break, I was looking it up for you!

Comment: Next, time you should consider giving people who is trying to help you the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Since all the settings are in the Options menu, I figured you would be able to find it yourself, but I updated the answer with the specifics just in case. You really feel that this still warrants a down vote?